# WebMock model's function when called via controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, webmock

I have existing functionality, where specs calls HTTP PUT method of a controller, which in-turn calls model's method to get some JSON data via. API.

```
class SomeModel
  def GetData()
    uri = URI.parse('http://api.mydomain.com/getmydata/123/ohmyurl')
    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :read_timeout => 200) do |http|
      request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
      response = http.request(request)
      unless response.body == "null"
        return JSON.parse(response.body)
      end
      #......
    end
  end
end

class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def update
    #...
    @model.GetData()
    #...
  end
end

#......specs............

put :update
```

I need to mock the API in `SomeModel`. So far I have tried:

```
#......specs............

    before do
        stub_request(:get, /api.mydomain.com/)
            .with(headers: {'Accept'=>'application/json' })
            .to_return(status: 200, body: {id: 1, secondParam: '324'}.to_json, headers: {})

    end

#.......

    put :update
    result = JSON.load response.body
    expect(result['secondParam']).to eq("324")
```

Which is not able to mock the API call and actual API is called.

*kindly ignore syntax errors*

Comment: Did you disable external requests in your `spec_helper.rb`? `WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)`

Comment: Yes, when disabled it ignores all the spec code, even ignores `byebug`